# Collection should not be empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using Meteor and I'm getting an error when I try to get data from a Collection. I have a file in package/lib folder where I'm doing this :

```
this.WidgetFactory = {};

WidgetFactory.getWidget = function(){
     console.log(Widgets.find().count());
}
```

In my client I'm just doing WidgetFactory.getWidget() and it logs me 0 (instead of 1). When I'm calling in chrome

```
> WidgetFactory.getWidget()
  7
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: In the console check if you have data by calling Widgets.find().fetch() On the client you need to subscribe to Widgets collection data

Comment: I have the correction result both on client console & server console. I did a subscription client side + publish server side

Comment: Where in your client code do you call subscription and WidgetFactory.getWidget()? Can you show the code in your question? If WidgetFactory.getWidget() is not in a reactive block (helper, autorun) you will get 0 on page load, because subscription is not ready yet.

Comment: have you tried `Widgets.find().fetch().count()` ?